# Keyword search parallel arrays

Tags: java

Hello I am trying to write code to keyword search parralele arrays I have 2 arrays

```
    String[] beerNames = new String[10]; //define berrNames array
    Double[] beerStrengths = new Double[10]; //define beerStrengths array        

    beerNames[0] = "Heineken"; //fill the arrays
    beerNames[1] = "Bud Light";
    beerNames[2] = "Coors Light";
    beerNames[3] = "Leffe Blonde";
    beerNames[4] = "Budweiser";
    beerNames[5] = "Erdinger Non-Alcoholic";
    beerNames[6] = "Bud Premier Select";
    beerNames[7] = "Corona";
    beerNames[8] = "Barefoot Bohemian";
    beerNames[9] = "3 Monts";

    beerStrengths[0] = 4.0;
    beerStrengths[1] = 4.2;
    beerStrengths[2] = 4.3;
    beerStrengths[3] = 6.6;
    beerStrengths[4] = 5.0;
    beerStrengths[5] = 0.0;
    beerStrengths[6] = 7.4;
    beerStrengths[7] = 4.6;
    beerStrengths[8] = 4.0;
    beerStrengths[9] = 8.5; //fill the arrays
```

I want to be able to search by keyword so if I enter bud I would get back a result of

The alcohol content of “Bud Light” is 4.2%
The alcohol content of “Budweiser” is 5.0%

Sadly I have no idea how to do this I have been looking at some code I have from searching a file 
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Search phrase: ");
        String search = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("imdb.txt"));
    // 1 9.1 243153 The Godfather (1972)

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        if (line.toLowerCase().contains(search)) {
            //System.out.println(line);
            displayMovieInfo(line);
        }
    }
}

public static void displayMovieInfo(String line) {
    Scanner lineScan = new Scanner(line);
    int rank = lineScan.nextInt();
    double rating = lineScan.nextDouble();
    lineScan.nextInt();

    String title = "";
    while (lineScan.hasNext()) {
        title = title + lineScan.next() + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(rank + "\t" + rating + "\t" + title);
}
```

But I cannot figure out how to convert this code any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array index for the first array, you know it for the second. This also sounds like a candidate for creating an object with two attributes:

```
public class BeerStrength  {
   private final String name;
   private final int strengthNum;
   public BeerStrength(String name, int strength_num)  {
      this.name = name;
      strengthNum = strength_num;
   }
   public String getName()  {
      return  name;
   }
   public int getStrength()  {
      return  strengthNum;
   }
}
```

Then you have an array of `BeerStrength`, which would make your parallel-array problem moot.

Comment: @Chris: if this answer has helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it as your answer by clicking on the big green checkmark. Best of luck and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of two arrays, just use a HashMap. Use String as your key, and Double as your value.  That way you can iterate over the keys and return the value.  You will dramatically cut down on your code and will be using only one data structure.

Comment: Our two answers together I think are the real answer. Key of beer name, value `BeerStrength`.

Comment: Add in @christopher's `equals` function, and we'll just have ourselves a big old Answer Smoothie.

Comment: Great minds think a like, don't they!  The Three Musty Steers strike again.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do, would be change your approach. If you find yourself handling several arrays, then there is usually a different approach you can take. For example, you could create a `Beer` class with `name` and `volume` as values.

```
public class Beer
{
    private String name;
    private double volume;

    public Beer(String name, double volume)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof Beer) {
           Beer beer = (Beer)o;

           if(this.name.equals(beer.getName())) {
               return true;
           }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getName() {return this.name; }
    public double getVolume() {return this.volume; }
}
```

Then you could create a bunch of `Beer` objects, by putting them in a `List`.

```
private List<Beer> beers;
```

And when populating, you do something like..

```
beers = new ArrayList<Beer>();

beers.add(new Beer("Budweiser", 5));
// Etc..
```

Now you're free to take input, and work out how to search :)